# Edit raw source of a sent/received email in an IMAP box with Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I connect a Gmail mailbox in IMAP with Thunderbird.

I can view an email's raw source with the "More" button > View Source.

**How can I edit the source of an already sent/received email?** (without re-sending the email to myself)

Why? Because I'd like to remove metadata like:

```
References: <AB+CD=EFgHI-JKlMNopqR_ST=U3-vwxy@mail.gmail.com>
In-Reply-To: <AB+CD=EFgHI-JKlMNopqR_ST=U3-vwxy@mail.gmail.com>
```

which causes the Gmail client to group multiple emails in a single thread. Note that I *don't want* to fully disable Conversation view/Thread grouping: I'd like to keep this feature ON, but only disable a wrong thread-grouping in a few hundreds of received/sent emails.

Note: I've already tried the Thunderbird extension [Header Tools Improved](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/header-tools-improved/?src=ss) but after editing the headers:

- the thread grouping for the 2 messages I tried it on isn't disabled
- it changes the email datetime as seen by Gmail, which I don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- In Thunderbird, copy the email from Gmail IMAP to a Local folder
- Delete the original email in Gmail client
- Edit the email in the Thunderbird Local folder with "Header Tools Improved"
- Move this email from Local folder back to IMAP

It's the only working way I found. Editing directly on IMAP doesn't work with Gmail.

I already had the same experience with this complex [Thunderbird+Gmail workflow](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95427/can-one-delete-a-gmail-attachment-but-keep-the-email/125147#125147).